# Can I create cookies using windows upon starting my Computer

Tags: javascript, html, windows, cookies, server

I don’t really know much about cookies, so sorry if the question isn’t really well asked.

Here is my problem. I am currently working on an Intra website using the file protocol to access it. (If required, I could setup the website online.) and I need to fetch the windows userName for each user as soon as the website is opened, to avoid having to use a login and a password.

My idea was to get the windows userName in the batch, and write it into a cookie so that my website could then access it.

If it is possible, could you possibly help me do it?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: cookies are basically a browser concept - so, not sure how windows can do that, easily

Comment: `file://` protocol does not always set cookies. Some browsers just silently fail on that. If you put it online or on an intranet domain to solve this issue, it's probably "easier" to write a program that generates a small JS script with the data you need and finally gets launched by the browser to implement the cookie. Personally though I'd just setup an LDAP server and connect all company wide login systems, including Windows / Unix / PHP / NodeJS etc to it. Centralized login database and much easier to realize / maintain.